# Package not available in 1304?

Tags: 13.04, keyboard

Is it normal that the package gnome15 is not available for 13.04 ?

I tried to follow these instructions

http://www.gnome15.org/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=22&Itemid=33

but received the following error message when doing apt-get update:
W: Failed to fetch http://www.gnome15.org/raring/./Packages  404  Not Found

Is there any workaround ?

Answer (score 1):

I can not find any repo for Ubuntu 13.04

I suggest you contact the gnome15 team - https://launchpad.net/~gnome15-team

In the absence of a repository you would need to build from source.

http://www.gnome15.org/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=5&Itemid=34

From the above link (I suggest you read it for details)

```
bzr branch lp:~tanktarta/gnome15/stable gnome15
```

Read The Install Manual

Most of Gnome15 uses autotools. Run the commands below, or for a more detailed explanation you should read the Installation Manual.

```
cd gnome15
./configure
make
```

Then:

```
sudo make install
```

Comment: There is no configure file in the gnome15 folder.

Answer (score 0):

For what it's worth it, after having no news for several months from the developer, I created an "unofficial" website for gnome15 and have packaged it for the newly released versions of the supported distributions (Fedora 18, Debian 7, Ubuntu 13.04, openSUSE 12.3...).

I also published new unofficial versions of Gnome15 (currently 0.9.4) who fixes some issues that users have talked about in the forums.

You can take a look at it here http://www.russo79.com/gnome15